# Interpreting ctree {partykit} output in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, cart

Data precisions :

- quotation is a dummy variable
- minute count all the minutes within a day
- temp is the temperature

Here is my code :

```
ctree <- ctree(quotation ~ minute + temp, data = visitquot)
print(ctree)

Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] minute <= 600
|   |   [3] minute <= 227
|   |   |   [4] temp <= -0.4259
|   |   |   |   [5] temp <= -2.3174: 0.015 (n = 6254, err = 89.7)
|   |   |   |   [6] temp > -2.3174
|   |   |   |   |   [7] minute <= 68: 0.028 (n = 4562, err = 126.3)
|   |   |   |   |   [8] minute > 68: 0.046 (n = 7100, err = 312.8)
|   |   |   [9] temp > -0.4259
|   |   |   |   [10] temp <= 6.0726: 0.015 (n = 56413, err = 860.5)
|   |   |   |   [11] temp > 6.0726: 0.019 (n = 39779, err = 758.9)
|   |   [12] minute > 227
|   |   |   [13] minute <= 501
|   |   |   |   [14] minute <= 291: 0.013 (n = 30671, err = 388.0)
|   |   |   |   [15] minute > 291: 0.009 (n = 559646, err = 5009.3)
|   |   |   [16] minute > 501
|   |   |   |   [17] temp <= 5.2105
|   |   |   |   |   [18] temp <= -1.8393: 0.009 (n = 66326, err = 617.1)
|   |   |   |   |   [19] temp > -1.8393: 0.012 (n = 355986, err = 4289.0)
|   |   |   |   [20] temp > 5.2105
|   |   |   |   |   [21] temp <= 13.6927: 0.014 (n = 287909, err = 3900.7)
|   |   |   |   |   [22] temp > 13.6927
|   |   |   |   |   |   [23] temp <= 14: 0.035 (n = 2769, err = 92.7)
|   |   |   |   |   |   [24] temp > 14: 0.007 (n = 2161, err = 15.9)
|   [25] minute > 600
|   |   [26] temp <= 1.6418
|   |   |   [27] temp <= -2.3366: 0.012 (n = 110810, err = 1268.1)
|   |   |   [28] temp > -2.3366: 0.014 (n = 584457, err = 7973.2)
|   |   [29] temp > 1.6418: 0.016 (n = 3753208, err = 57864.3)
```

Then I ploted the tree :

```
plot(ctree, type = "simple")
```

And here is a part of the output :

[image]

**My questions are :**

1. In the first output from `print(ctree)`, lets take the last line `[29] temp > 1.6418: 0.016 (n = 3753208, err = 57864.3)`. What does the value `0.016` means ? is that a p-value ? And what does `err = 57864.3` means ? It can't be a count of attribution error because it is a float number.
2. I could not find anywhere a similar output that I have in the grey square. If someone knows how to interpret it. And how can a p-value be negative ?

[Here same code but different output](http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/decision-tree)

Comment: I would suggest to start by trying the same process using `party` package instead of `partykit`. I think the `type='simple'` plot works better that way. What is your dummy variables' values? Is it binary, categorical? Is this a classification tree or regression tree? Would be good to see a summary of your 3 variables. I have a feeling that your dummy (output) variable is numeric but the model treats it as scale variable and not categorical.

Comment: Then I think that 0.016 you get is the average of the 0s and 1s. You can see it as the % of 1s (success classes), but the right way to do it is to use `as.character` instead of using factors. You have to let the model know that those 0s and 1s are labels and not real numbers.

Comment: The variable is`numeric` and `quotation` is composed of `0` and `1`.
How can I know if it is a regression or categorical tree ?
I will test right away with `quotation` as a factor and then with the `party` package.
However, what I understand from your answer is that the current output isn't normal right ?

Comment: If your output variable is a scale variable the method recognises it and builds a regression tree. If your output is categorical the method will build a classification tree. There's also some hint based on your `err` values. If it's a classification tree those will be a missclasification %.

Comment: As for the `plot(..., type = "simple")` problem. I still need to check why this currently does not work as desired in `partykit` but will try to fix this soon. In the meantime, just do `plot(as.simpleparty(ctree))` which generates the desired plot. (This is better than going back to the old `party` implementation...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the `0.016` that you are seeing is the average of `quotation` while `err` is just the SSE.

I'm old school and don't know how to exactly show this using the new `partykit` package (maybe @Achim could illustrate), but I can show you how this done using the older `party` package.

So let's create some reproducible example

```
library(partykit)
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq)
print(airct)
# Model formula:
#   Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + Month + Day
# 
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] Temp <= 82
# |   |   [3] Wind <= 6.9: 55.600 (n = 10, err = 21946.4)
# |   |   [4] Wind > 6.9
# |   |   |   [5] Temp <= 77: 18.479 (n = 48, err = 3956.0)
# |   |   |   [6] Temp > 77: 31.143 (n = 21, err = 4620.6)
# |   [7] Temp > 82
# |   |   [8] Wind <= 10.3: 81.633 (n = 30, err = 15119.0)
# |   |   [9] Wind > 10.3: 48.714 (n = 7, err = 1183.4)
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    4
# Number of terminal nodes: 5
```

Now let's `dtach` the `partykit` package and fit the same tree using `party` and calculate the same values

```
detach("package:partykit", unload=TRUE)
library(party)
airct <- party::ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq)

t(sapply(unique(where(airct)), function(x) {
  n <- nodes(airct, x)[[1]]
  Ozone <- airq[as.logical(n$weights), "Ozone"]
  cbind.data.frame("Node" = as.integer(x), 
                   "n" = length(Ozone), 
                   "Avg."= mean(Ozone), 
                   "Variance"= var(Ozone), 
                   "SSE" = sum((Ozone - mean(Ozone))^2))  
}))

#      Node n  Avg.     Variance SSE     
# [1,] 5    48 18.47917 84.16977 3955.979
# [2,] 3    10 55.6     2438.489 21946.4 
# [3,] 6    21 31.14286 231.0286 4620.571
# [4,] 9    7  48.71429 197.2381 1183.429
# [5,] 8    30 81.63333 521.3437 15118.97
```

I think it is easy to see from the output which is which

---

What the code above does is basically extract the information of `Ozone` information out of the fitted tree per each inner node and calculate the relevant statistics

---

As per the `P-value`s, this seems like some type of printing bug, here's an example how you can calculate the `P-value`s in the inner nodes

```
terNodes <- unique(where(airct))
setdiff(1:max(terNodes), terNodes)

sapply(setdiff(1:max(terNodes), terNodes), function(x) {
          n <- nodes(airct, x)[[1]]
          pvalue <- 1 - nodes(airct, x)[[1]]$criterion$maxcriterion
          plab <- ifelse(pvalue < 10^(-3),
                         paste("p <", 10^(-3)),
                         paste("p =", round(pvalue, digits = 3)))
          c("Node" = x, "P-value" = plab)
})

#         [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       
# Node    "1"         "2"         "4"         "7"        
# P-value "p < 0.001" "p = 0.002" "p = 0.003" "p = 0.003"
```

---

As a side note, if `quotation` is a dummy variable, you should probably fit a *classification* tree (i.e. convert it to a factor) rather a *regression* tree like you are doing

Comment: I can't upvote your answer yet due to lack of reputation but thanks.
Your answer combined with @Antoniosk helped me greatly !

Comment: Regarding that negative P-value you are seing. It looks like a bug to me as P-value can't be negative by definition. I'm sure @Achim will have something to add on that matter.

Comment: Anyway, also added an illustration regarding how to calculate p-values in the inner nodes- see edit.

Comment: To obtain the node-specific summaries, the simplest solution (IMHO) is to just do a `tapply()` on the response by the corresponding terminal nodes, computing any function you desire, e.g., `tapply(airq$Ozone, predict(airct, type = "node"), function(y) c("n" = length(y), "Avg." = mean(y), "Variance" = var(y), "SSE" = sum((y - mean(y))^2)))`. You can also do a subsequent `do.call("rbind", ...)` or use some other kind of aggregation...

Comment: To extract the p-values, you can easily extract these in the new `partykit` version. To obtain the p-values from _all_ tests carried out, just do `library("strucchange")` and then `sctest(airct)`. From this you can easily get the minimum or any other summary you desire. Furthermore, youcan also just extract the minimal p-value stored in each node (if any), by `nodeapply(airct, ids = nodeids(airct), FUN = function(n) info_node(n)$p.value)`.

Comment: As for the negative p-values stored in the `$criterion` shown in the (undesired) `type="simple"` plot: These are actually log-p-values which are numerically much more stable in case of highly significant tests. If queried with `sctest(...)` they are transformed back to p-values as one would expect. The log-p-values are not intended to be directly shown/accessed.

Comment: @AchimZeileis I think you should post an answer including all of this info regarding `partykit` :). I would never think those are log-p-values too.

Comment: As I said: These are not intended to be displayed directly to the user. They are stored there for internal computations. But I'll try to collect everything in another answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. Now another problem arise, the fact that every leaf as an `average` of `0`. I wonder if this comes from the fact that their is only `"0.014%"` of `1` in `quotation` makingg it unlikely to have a leaf with a high proba to get a `1`.
Do you think this deserve another question ? I could not find any relevant info on this...

Comment: It's probably a printing issue. Try setting `options(digits = 22)` and then try again.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @DavidArenburg, I'm collecting my comments here in another answer for easier references.

(1) If your response is binary, you need to turn it into a factor. Otherwise the inference employed when growing the tree is not what it should be, and also the predictions, visualizations, and error measures are not those intended for classification. See the replies by @DavidArenburg and @AntoniosK for further examples. In general: Also the explanatory variables need to have appropriate classes (numeric, factor, ordered factor) to be processed correctly when growing the tree.

(2) The `plot(..., type = "simple")` currently does not work as desired - in other words this is a bug. We will fix the `partykit` package in due course. For the moment you can easily work around it by using `plot(as.simpleparty(...))`. As a reproducible example:

```
library("partykit")
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes", package = "mlbench")
ct <- ctree(diabetes ~ ., data = PimaIndiansDiabetes)
plot(as.simpleparty(ct))
```

[image: simpleparty]

(3) The `$criterion` table erroneously shown currently in the `type = "simple"` plot contains the test statistics and corresponding *log* 1-p values from the conditional inference conducted in each node. The log rather than the p-value is used because it is numerically much more stable when used for comparisons, computing the minimal value, etc. Note that the p-values can become extremely small when significant. As an example consider the test results corresponding to the first node from the tree above:

```
nodeapply(ct, ids = 1, function(n) info_node(n)$criterion)
## $`1`
##                pregnant       glucose   pressure   triceps      insulin
## statistic  3.631413e+00  5.117841e+00  1.1778530  1.455334  2.570457503
## p.value   -6.380290e-09 -2.710725e-37 -0.5937987 -0.313498 -0.002398554
##                    mass      pedigree           age
## statistic  4.185236e+00  3.143294e+00  3.774507e+00
## p.value   -4.181295e-15 -1.180135e-05 -3.262459e-10
```

(4) To extract the actual p-values (without log), there is an extractor function `sctest()` (for *structural change test*) which is used by the `strucchange` package and also for the parameter instability tests in the `mob()` trees. In the example above:

```
library("strucchange")
sctest(ct, node = 1)
##               pregnant  glucose  pressure   triceps     insulin         mass
## statistic 3.776615e+01 166.9745 3.2473947 4.2859164 13.07180346 6.570902e+01
## p.value   6.380290e-09   0.0000 0.4477744 0.2691142  0.00239568 4.218847e-15
##               pedigree          age
## statistic 2.318009e+01 4.357601e+01
## p.value   1.180128e-05 3.262459e-10
```

Note that one p-value (glucose) becomes zero while its log(1 - p) is very close to zero but not quite. To only extract the minimal p-values from the selected partitioning variable (if any), you can again use the `nodeapply()` function to obtain it from each node's `$info`:

```
nodeapply(ct, ids = nodeids(ct), function(n) info_node(n)$p.value)
## $`1`
## glucose 
##       0 
## 
## $`2`
##          age 
## 6.048661e-07 
## 
## $`3`
##        mass 
## 0.001169778 
## 
## ...
```

(5) If you want to summarize the response in each terminal node, the easiest solution (IMHO) is to do a simple `tapply()` on the response variable by the node groups, supplying any summary function you want. For a simpler overview, you can also `rbind()` this etc. For example:

```
tab <- tapply(PimaIndiansDiabetes$diabetes, predict(ct, type = "node"),
  function(y) c("n" = length(y), 100 * prop.table(table(y))))
do.call("rbind", tab)
##      n      neg        pos
## 5  144 99.30556  0.6944444
## 6    7 85.71429 14.2857143
## 7  120 82.50000 17.5000000
## 8  214 66.82243 33.1775701
## 11  53 79.24528 20.7547170
## 12 108 39.81481 60.1851852
## 13 122 19.67213 80.3278689
```

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to @DavidArenburg 's great answer I'll show you the difference in outputs between regression and classification trees

```
library(partykit)

# data
airquality = data.frame(airquality)

# create a numeric binary variable as dependent variable
airquality$OzoneClass = 0
airquality$OzoneClass[airquality$Ozone>=34] =1

# regression tree with scale dependent variable
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(OzoneClass ~ Temp, data = airq)
print(airct)

# Model formula:
#   OzoneClass ~ Temp
# 
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] Temp <= 82
# |   |   [3] Temp <= 77: 0.096 (n = 52, err = 4.5)
# |   |   [4] Temp > 77: 0.519 (n = 27, err = 6.7)
# |   [5] Temp > 82: 0.973 (n = 37, err = 1.0)
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    2
# Number of terminal nodes: 3




# create a categorical binary variable as dependent variable
airquality$OzoneClass = 0
airquality$OzoneClass[airquality$Ozone>=34] =1
airquality$OzoneClass = as.factor(airquality$OzoneClass)

# classification tree
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(OzoneClass ~ Temp, data = airq)
print(airct)

# Model formula:
#   OzoneClass ~ Temp
# 
# Fitted party:
#   [1] root
# |   [2] Temp <= 82
# |   |   [3] Temp <= 77: 0 (n = 52, err = 9.6%)
# |   |   [4] Temp > 77: 1 (n = 27, err = 48.1%)
# |   [5] Temp > 82: 1 (n = 37, err = 2.7%)
# 
# Number of inner nodes:    2
# Number of terminal nodes: 3
```

Note how (a) the values of the trees change from an average value of 0s and 1s (regression tree) to the most likely class 0/1 (classification tree) and (b) the `err` values from a number (error) become a percentage (missclassification).